# How to use facebook api graph as a url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get success on `Graph API Explorer` like in image

```
https://i.imgur.com/0UbLNej.png
```

Then i tried to use as URL to do like this.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?method=GET&path=5550296508_10157403661361509%2Fattachments&version=v2.10/access_token=my_tokon
```

But not work, it's show error text.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "C8XLXuSaBez"
   }
}
```

How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You need an `access_token` to get the response from Facebook Graph Api. you are trying to get `attachments` using  `post-id` from [/v2.10/{post-id}/attachments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/attachment) endpoint.

In the Graph API Explorer, you can generate access_token using `get_token` button, then you can frame URL to get response as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/5550296508_10157403661361509/attachments?access_token={access_token}
```

Comment: But result on https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/5550296508_10157403661361509/attachments?access_token={access_token}

no same result on https://i.imgur.com/0UbLNej.png

eg: image url on api is https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBe7JCl2WJwcka7&w=439&h=439&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi2.cdn.turner.com%2Fmoney%2Fdam%2Fassets%2F171003123715-trump-puerto-rico-780x439.jpg&cfs=1&sx=187&sy=0&sw=439&sh=439&_nc_eui2=v1%3AAeHrvWeYlczDDOpbMAtXicLDGua52cljXuLof4LJKzFGeDMjrUI_6R0zC9o-nwQ-oXuo39d-zp4h-lgIruU75auw&_nc_hash=AQDiNGzHFuQTXckS

Comment: but image url on https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/5550296508_10157403661361509/attachments?access_token={access_token} is https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBe7JCl2WJwcka7&w=439&h=439&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi2.cdn.turner.com\u00252Fmoney\u00252Fdam\u00252Fassets\u00252F171003123715-trump-puerto-rico-780x439.jpg&cfs=1&sx=187&sy=0&sw=439&sh=439&_nc_eui2=v1\u00253AAeHrtFRhNdzuXjeZrRcBCi9zae7r4gtKC5RyGnT8xRo746mrYySQo4WXLcU2Uh4xxhLqdBlvvOzL6T7m4Wf_437Ri7SbH0-UJUG1xDhon4hUCw&_nc_hash=AQC5byNv6it0UMO0

Comment: and picture are not same

Comment: could you please show me picture url from your result

Comment: WOW But why i get this picture url ?
https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBe7JCl2WJwcka7&w=439&h=439&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi2.cdn.turner.com\u00252Fmoney\u00252Fdam\u00252Fassets\u00252F171003123715-trump-puerto-rico-780x439.jpg&cfs=1&sx=187&sy=0&sw=439&sh=439&_nc_hash=AQAWBS_QFw8q-GML

Comment: how can i do ? please tell me ^_^

Comment: [image]https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBe7JCl2WJwcka7&w=439&h=439&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi2.cdn.turner.com\u00252Fmoney\u00252Fdam\u00252Fassets\u00252F171003123715-trump-puerto-rico-780x439.jpg&cfs=1&sx=187&sy=0&sw=439&sh=439&_nc_eui2=v1\u00253AAeHrtFRhNdzuXjeZrRcBCi9zae7r4gtKC5RyGnT8xRo746mrYySQo4WXLcU2Uh4xxhLqdBlvvOzL6T7m4Wf_437Ri7SbH0-UJUG1xDhon4hUCw&_nc_hash=AQC5byNv6it0UMO0

Comment: [image](https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBe7JCl2WJwcka7&w=439&h=439&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi2.cdn.turner.com\u00252Fmoney\u00252Fdam\u00252Fassets\u00252F171003123715-trump-puerto-rico-780x439.jpg&cfs=1&sx=187&sy=0&sw=439&sh=439&_nc_eui2=v1\u00253AAeHrtFRhNdzuXjeZrRcBCi9zae7r4gtKC5RyGnT8xRo746mrYySQo4WXLcU2Uh4xxhLqdBlvvOzL6T7m4Wf_437Ri7SbH0-UJUG1xDhon4hUCw&_nc_hash=AQC5byNv6it0UMO0)